# xentop gives static info about memory usage

Tags: memory, monitoring, xen

I am using CentOS 6.5 and Xen 4.2.4-30

xentop does not change `MEM(%)` at all.

```
      NAME  STATE   CPU(sec) CPU(%)     MEM(k) MEM(%)  MAXMEM(k) MAXMEM(%) VCPUS NETS NETTX(k) NETRX(k) VBDS   VBD_OO   VBD_RD   VBD_WR  VBD_RSECT  VBD_WSECT SSID
  Domain-0 -----r         68    0.0    1048568   25.0    1048576      25.0     1    0        0        0    0        0        0        0          0          0    0
       vm1 --b---          7    0.0    1536000   36.6    1536000      36.6     1    1       49        0    1        0     6518      433      95640       4034    0
       vm2 --b---          8    0.0    1536000   36.6    1536000      36.6     1    1       55        5    1        0     6562      551      97336       5090    0
```

Is there anyway to get how much of the allocated memory for each VM like CPU(%) in `xentop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Xen (ie. I have no practical experience with it) but I did find this thread which would seem to indicate that you can never get the "actual" memory utilizations from the guest VMs from Dom0 via `xentop`.

- [Monitoring domU real memory usage](http://xen.1045712.n5.nabble.com/Monitoring-domU-real-memory-usage-td2543976.html)

There is this comment at the end of the thread:

> This information is not available from domain0 by default but can be sent from each domU via xenstore.  Look at the shell scripts in xenballoond for an example of how to do that.  Basically, you need a shell script running in each domU to put the information (e.g. /proc/meminfo) into xenstore and a shell script in dom0 to read it and print it.